# Fedena SMS Settings for SMS Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedena

I got the following coed from my SMS Gateway and I want to use the code in my fedena SMS settings, I tried but I get not response.

Below is the code I got from SMS Gateway.

```
http://sms.smsgateway.net/api/api_http.php?
username=abcd&password=@abcd&sender=My Name
&to=923131234567&text=Hello%20world
&type=text
```

I changed the sms_settings.yml as below but I get no response, and SMS is not sending.

```
sms_settings:
 username: abcd
 password: @abcd
 sendername: sender
 host_url: http://sms.smsgateway.net/api/api_http.php
 success_code: "OK"

parameter_mappings:
 username: username
 password: password
 sendername: My Name
 message: text
 phone: to

# Additional parameters to be added should given in the format "param1=value1&param2=value2&..."
additional_parameters: "type=text"
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. are you using some gem to send SMS? the first block is not "a code", it's the url example for an HTTP request to an API.

Comment: dear the question is about the School Management System Software fedena. And the first lines of code is a HTTP request to api , used to send SMS, and I want to implement it in fedena for sending sms, for which I have to make changes in sms_settings.yml according to the above HTTP request.